# What will happen to flag marked as "eventinvalidated"?

Tags: support, flags

A few days ago, someone posted a question about updating dataset. After some questions/comments to his question, it didn't receive answers (and no up/down vote).

1 or 2 days later, the user posted the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18390087/how-to-refresh-update-dataset-in-vb-net-for-windows-forms) (he just reformulated the question, posted less code and with bad formatting, the code doesn't compile due to missing `'` for comments), so it would be harder to get answer for this question . The question received a +1. [Va comprendre Charles](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/va_comprendre_Charles)

I flagged this question as a duplicate of the previous and asked user to edit the previous instead of creating a new one, but he deleted the previous.

I do not blame the asker, I understand he wanted to keep it's 5 points rep  :) And it seems he solved his problem later.

But now the flag is marked with *eventinvalidated* because it is impossible now to accept or reject it?

Since my flag is no longer appropriate, I am just curious about what could happen to this flag?